# How do I tell npm to install specific version of library?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, package.json

As a part of security vulnerability fix, I need update one of the transitive dependency.

The vulnerability is in minimist package, which needs to be updated to 0.2.1.

```
minimist :: 0.0.8 >> Mypackage >> node:npm:artifactory/npm-dcloud:less:3.9.0 >> node:npm:artifactory/npm-dcloud:mkdirp:0.5.1
```

This is how the vulnerable package is reported in my system.So I need to tell less:3.9.0 that it should use specific version of minimist when it is fetched in one of its dependencies from mkdirp.

As of now my package.json looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
   .......
   .......
    "less": "^3.0.4",

   .......
  }
```

I have two queries here:

1. Why does package-lock.json has less version as 3.9.0 when I have 3.0.4 in package.json?In npm list also, I see only 3.9.0.
2. How can I inform npm to use minimist 0.2.1 instead 0.0.8 as reported above?

npm ls  minimist

```
├─┬ babel-cli@6.26.0
│ └─┬ chokidar@1.7.0
│   └─┬ fsevents@1.1.3
│     └─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
│       ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│       │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
│       └─┬ rc@1.2.1
│         └── minimist@1.2.0 
├─┬ babel-loader@7.1.5
│ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│   └── minimist@0.0.8 
├─┬ grunt@1.0.1
│ └─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│   └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│     └── minimist@1.2.0 
├─┬ karma@1.5.0
│ └─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│   └── minimist@0.0.10 
├─┬ karma-mocha@1.3.0
│ └── minimist@1.2.0 
├── minimist@0.2.1 
├─┬ phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16
│ └─┬ extract-zip@1.6.6
│   └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
│     └── minimist@0.0.8 
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.12.0
│ └─┬ watchpack@1.6.0
│   └─┬ chokidar@2.0.4
│     └─┬ fsevents@1.2.4
│       └─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
│         ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│         │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
│         └─┬ rc@1.2.7
│           └── minimist@1.2.0 
└─┬ webpack-dev-server@2.9.7
  └─┬ internal-ip@1.2.0
    └─┬ meow@3.7.0
      └── minimist@1.2.0 

npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^2.0.0, required by grunt-webpack@2.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^1.1.0 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta.0 || ^2.2.0-rc.0, required by karma-webpack@2.0.3
```

I have tried overrides as mentioned

```
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides
as follow:
 "overrides": {
    "mkdirp": {
      "minimist": "0.2.1"
    }
```

but still minimist older version is coming

Comment: 1. Because `^3.0.4` doesn't mean _exactly_ 3.0.4, see e.g. https://semver.npmjs.com/. 2. As far as I can see `less@3.9.0` would use `minimist@1.2.6` (via `mkdirp@^0.5.0` -> `minimist@^1.2.6`), have you run e.g. `npm audit fix`, `npm update`, ...? Try `npm ls minimist` to see why it's being included.

Comment: As i saw, less@3.9.0 there are both mkdirp 0.5.0 and 0.5.1 in my package-lock.json and both requires "minimist": "0.0.8". Is there a simple way where I can tell in package-lock.json to use "minimist": "0.2.1" where-ever required?

Comment: No, because `mkdirp@0.5.0` requires `minimist@0.0.8` exactly.

Comment: I tried override mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096862/how-do-you-bump-a-transitive-dependency-in-package-lock-json. It also did not work. There must be some way to specify the transitive dependency we want to use?

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install module_name@version_number
npm install less@3.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Second query:

1. rm -rf node_modules/
2. rm package-lock.json
3. In the package.json file it is possible to add the transitive dependency version.

   ```
   "resolutions": {
       "minimist": "0.2.1"
   },
   ```
4. npm install

:)

Comment: It did not work.I still see in my pakcage-lock.json

Comment: Did not work.I still see following in my package-lock.json"minimist": {
          "version": "0.0.8",
   "resolved": "https://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dcloud/minimist/-/minimist-0.0.8.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-hX/Kv8M5fSYluCKCYuhqp6ARsF0=",
   "dev": true
      },
"mkdirp": {
"version": "0.5.1",
  "resolved": "https://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dcloud/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.1.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-MAV0OOrGz3+MR2fzhkjWaX11yQM=",
          "dev": true,
          "requires": {
            "minimist": "0.0.8"
          }
        },

Comment: Hey, try delete package-lock.json  and run npm install